# Add custom requred checkbox to checkout Order Review step

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, customer, onepage-checkout

I want to add a custom required checkbox to checkout, in Order Review step.

I don't want to store anywere this value, only to show to the customer, before placing orders.

Does anyone know where i need to place my checkbox, and can i make this required?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/223249/how-to-create-custom-checkbox-field-for-term-and-conditions-in-one-page-checkout/344623#344623

Answer (score 0):

Go to **System Config -> Sales -> Checkout -> Checkout Options** and change **Enable Terms and Conditions** to Yes.

Comment: I already did it. now showing